# Using AngularJS ng-include in a form builder

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing a form builder in AngularJS using a component. You can drag and drop elements into the form. So you can drag a section into the form, and then drag elements such as a checkbox into the section. I am using ng-include to include the html templates for the elements.

It all works fine. However, I need to have sections within sections.

If I ng-include a section in a section, it obviously becomes a recursive nightmare, and I have not found a way to break out of the recursion.

I can get it working to one level by having a separate subsection template, but I need multiple levels.

I can get multiple levels working by hard-coding a fixed number of subsections to the section template, but this is not an elegant solution, and has other draw backs which makes it unfeasible.

I was wondering if anyone can point me in the write direction for a solution to this. Not sure whether I should be using directives or separate components to add the section elements, rather than using ng-include. I can't see how this could solve the recursive issue though.

This is an example of the ng-include being used to add an element within the section template.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.componentArray track by $index">
  <div
    ng-if="item.sectionId === sectionItem.id || item.parentSectionId === sectionItem.id"
    ng-include="$ctrl.getHtmlTemplate(item.type)"
  ></div>
</div>
```

Appreciate any help.

==========================================

Here is more detail and some test code. Please don't judge the code too much!! It's just test code at the moment to try and get the logic correct :) I have not used ng-include before and normally only use components and very occasionally directives.

This version works to one nested subsection level. If I take the check out for !item.processed, I get the recursive issue.

The main controller template draws the layout and adds the first section.

This is the first section being added

`<div ng-include="$ctrl.getHtmlTemplate('section')"></div>`

This is the section template

```
<!--parent section -->
<div ng-repeat="sectionItem in $ctrl.sectionArray track by $index">
  <div
    ng-if="sectionItem.type !== 'subSection'"
    droppable
    ng-drop="true"
    id="section{{ sectionItem.id }}"
    resizable
    r-directions="['bottom']"
    ng-mouseover="$ctrl.componentHover($event)"
  >
    <div>
      <input
        placeholder="SECTION TITLE"
        ng-click="$ctrl.editComponent($index, 'section')"
        ng-model="sectionItem.sectionTitle"
      />
    </div>

    <div ng-if="$ctrl.componentHovering" class="drop-component-text">Drop Components Here</div>
    <div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.componentArray track by $index">
      <div
        ng-if="item.sectionId === sectionItem.id || item.parentSectionId === sectionItem.id"
        id="section{{ item.sectionId }}"
        ng-click="::$ctrl.focusComponentInput(item.id)"
      >
        <div ng-include="$ctrl.getHtmlTemplate(item.type, item)"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--end parent section-->
```

This is the first subsection template

```
<!-- subsection 1-->
<div
  droppable
  ng-drop="true"
  id="section{{ item.sectionId }}"
  style="margin-bottom:40px;"
  resizable
  r-directions="['bottom']"
  ng-mouseover="$ctrl.componentHover($event)"
>
  <div>
    <input
      placeholder="SECTION TITLE"
      ng-click="$ctrl.editComponent($index, 'section')"
      ng-model="item.sectionTitle"
    />
  </div>
  <div ng-if="$ctrl.componentHovering" class="drop-component-text">Drop Components Here</div>
  <div ng-repeat="item2 in $ctrl.componentArray track by $index">
    <div id="comp{{ item2.id }}" 
      <div
        ng-if="(item.sectionId === item2.parentSectionId || item.sectionId === item2.sectionId) && !item2.processed"
        ng-include="$ctrl.getHtmlTemplate(item2.type, item2)"
      ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are separate subsection templates for each level, and increasing the item counts each time to call the correct subsection template and set the correct id's. However only the first subsection is added recursively when the item.processed check is removed.

This is part of the controller

```
addFirstSection() {
    this.sectionId = 0;
    this.sectionArray.push({
      type: 'section',
      id: this.sectionId,
      sectionTitle: '',
    });
  }


getHtmlTemplate(item, i) {
    switch (item) {
      case 'subSection':
        if (i) {
          i.processed = true;
        }
        return './templates/subSection.tpl.html';
      case 'section':
        return './templates/section.tpl.html';
      case 'checkbox':
        return './templates/checkbox.tpl.html';
      case 'input':
        return './templates/input.tpl.html';
      case 'textarea':
        return './templates/textarea.tpl.html';
      case 'radio':
        return './templates/radio.tpl.html';
      case 'select':
        return './templates/select.tpl.html';
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
```

When a component or subsection is dropped into a section, it is added to the componentArray

```
  onDrop($event) {
    this.$timeout(() => {
      this.componentHovering = false;

      angular.forEach(this.sectionArray, section => {
        if (this.current) {`enter code here`
          this.currentIdStripped = Number(this.current.substring(7, 8));

          // eslint-disable-next-line eqeqeq
          if (this.current.substring(7, 8) == section.id) {
            const sectionElement = angular
              .element(`#section${this.current.substring(7, 8)}`)[0]
              .getBoundingClientRect();

            if (
              this.x > sectionElement.left &&
              this.y > sectionElement.top &&
              this.x < sectionElement.right &&
              this.y < sectionElement.bottom
            ) {
              if ($event.target.localName === 'input') {
                $event.target.id = 'componentInput';
              }

              if ($event.target.localName === 'textarea') {
                $event.target.id = 'componentTextarea';
              }

              if ($event.target.localName === 'select') {
                $event.target.id = 'componentSelect';
              }

              switch ($event.target.id) {
                case 'componentSection':
                case 'componentSectionLabel':
                  this.componentArray.push({
                    processed: false,
                    type: 'subSection',
                    sectionId: ++this.sectionId,
                    parentSectionId: section.id,
                    id: this.sectionId,
                    label: '',
                  });
                  this.sectionArray.push({
                    processed: false,
                    type: 'subSection',                    
                    sectionId: this.sectionId,
                    parentSectionId: section.id,
                    id: this.sectionId,
                    label: '',
                  });
                  this.sectionAdded = true;
                  break;
                case 'componentCheckbox':
                case 'componentCheckboxLabel':
                  this.componentArray.push({
                    processed: false,
                    id: this.componentIndex++, //let the id be the index
                    sectionId: section.id,
                    sectionCode: section.code,
                    type: 'checkbox',                    
                    sectionTitle: '',
                  });
                  break;
                case 'componentRadio':
                case 'componentRadioLabel':
                  this.componentArray.push({
                    id: this.componentIndex++,
                    sectionId: section.id,                   
                    type: 'radio',                  
                    label: '',
                  });
                  break;
                case 'componentSelect':
                case 'componentSelectLabel':
                  this.componentArray.push({
                    id: this.componentIndex++,
                    sectionId: section.id,
                   
                    type: 'select',
                   
                    label: '',
                  });
                  break;
                case 'componentInput':
                case 'componentInputLabel':
                  this.componentArray.push({
                    id: this.componentIndex++,
                    sectionId: section.id,                  
                    type: 'input',                    
                    label: '',
                  });
                  break;
                case 'componentTextarea':
                case 'componentTextareaLabel':
                  this.componentArray.push({
                    id: this.componentIndex++,
                    sectionId: section.id,                   
                    type: 'textarea',                    
                    label: '',
                  });
                  break;
                default:
              }
            }
          }
        }
      });

      // Add sections

      if (this.sectionAdded) {
        this.sectionSelected = false;
        this.sectionAdded = false;
      }

      if (this.sectionSelected) {
        const panel = angular.element('#panel')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        if (
          this.x > panel.left &&
          this.y > panel.top &&
          this.x < panel.right &&
          this.y < panel.bottom
        ) {
          this.sectionArray.push({
            type: 'section',
            id: ++this.sectionId,   
            label: '',
          });
        }
        this.sectionSelected = false;
      }
    }, 200);
  }
```

Comment: I've only ever used directives for this and I don't see a recursive problem using them. I do recommend that you set a max depth with your inner sections tho.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, then I believe your issue is misusing your template. This is hard to explain abstractly without seeing more of your code though, so please post more code showing a full example of this infinite recursion issue in a section, including the controller and/or link logic, as well as the template being included.

Comment: I added more detail above.

Comment: I think I have worked out how to do this. The sections should be components, and the child elements are passed in, which may include section components. I will try it out next week and let you know.